# XML Jackson binding with a not really nested XML in Kotlin

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have "a not nice looking" XML. (yes it's valid but different to the ones I normally get and where I know how to deal with it)

Normally I wanted so see something like:

```
<Parent....>
  <Books>
    <Book ...>
    <Book ...>
    <Book ...>
  </Books>
</Parent>
```

my Data Class for the abvoe XML would look like this:

```
data class Parent(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Books")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper
    var books: List<Book> 
)

data class Book(
    .....
    )
```

but unfortunately our incoming XML looks like this:

```
<Parent....>
    <Book ...>
    <Something>
    <Book ....>
    <Something>
    <Book ...>
</parent>
```

So I'm struggling with matching this with a normal Jackson Mapper, without using a custom one.
(and if I need a custom one, how it needs to look like?)

My mapper looks like this:

```
val kotlinModule: KotlinModule = KotlinModule.Builder()
                .strictNullChecks(false)
                .nullIsSameAsDefault(true) // needed, else it will break for null https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/130#issuecomment-546625625
                .build()

val xmlMapper =
                XmlMapper(JacksonXmlModule())
                        .registerModule(kotlinModule)
                        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
                        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) // to parse the dates as LocalDate, else parsing error
                        .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
                        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
                        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
```

Comment: Where is the "Something" even coming from?

Comment: @daniu that's how it looks.
the xml is passing every xml validator, so it's valid and not malformed.
of course, in our project it's not called something, it makes totally sense, but I have no idea how to match this with Jackson / or how to match with a custom one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deserializing such an XML there's two tricks you can use:

- Explicitly turning off wrapping for your `List<Book>`, as they are sitting directly in the `Parent`
- Working around engine limitations with a custom setter, a solution proposed in GitHub issue [#275](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/275#issuecomment-352700025)

More specifically, you can annotate your classes as such to allow deserialization of your example:

```kotlin
@JacksonXmlRootElement
class Parent {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Book")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    var books: List<Book> = ArrayList()
        set(value) {
            field = books + value
        }
}

data class Book(
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    val title: String
)
```

I uploaded a full example, which uses your Jackson config and sample XML, as a Kotlin Script to [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mKeRix/526aae97ae51a2be4fec750522449c02). It also shows the output of the deserialized XML at the bottom.